# How to split Chinese char array by a specific delimiter `……` (non-single chars) in standard C?

Tags: c

When I tried to split a char array in standard C. The problem is that it cannot show full char (only return `\n发\n办法` in this example) when input is Chinese characters with `……` just like, `印发……办法`. However, it is okay if the input is `abc……def` or `印发...办法`. Why and how to solve this problem?

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void split(char* str)
{
    char* token;
    const char delim[] = "……";
    token = strtok(str, delim); //it is a c++ method
    while (token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char ipt1[] = "印发……办法";
    split(ipt1);
}
```

Comment: You probably want wide character functions. Or a Unicode string library.

Comment: Your delimiter string `"……"` consists of two ellipsis, but `strtok()` will not look for consecutive characters — it looks for any byte in the delimiter string.  And that mention of 'byte' identifies the rest of the problem — to the extent that `strtok()` is suitable for anything, it is only suitable for analyzing single-byte code sets.  That rules out UTF-8 (and variations such as GB18030).  You probably need to look at the wide-character functions (such as `wcstok()`).  In standard C, there aren't any 'mbs*()` analogues to functions such as `strcpy()` and `wcscpy()` — which is a bit puzzling.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I have rewrite part of my code, actually I need to write a dll file, so c, not cpp, is necessary for me,  but now it show a messy code...

Comment: Your `printf()` statement should really use a format string (e.g. `printf("%s\n", token);`) or perhaps it should use `puts(token);`.  However, the code is now C, not C++.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how to use wcstok to split char array, could you please give more details?

Comment: Note that you should choose one language, C or C++, and you should not attempt to ask two questions in one.  If you want a C++ solution, ask a question about C++, showing C++ code using `std::string`.  If you leave the code as shown, it is C because it is not using any C++ features.  This was fixed up back in July; it was also unfixed in July.  It has been fixed to "C only" once more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 or other multibyte encoding represent ideographs, or ideograms, as sequence of multiple bytes. A single Chinese ideograph consists of ***multiple*** `char`s in UTF-8, for a single ideograph.

`strtok` doesn't know anything about multibyte ideographs. It recognizes delimiters as ***single*** chars. The second parameter to `strtok` is a character string, and every ***individual*** `char` value in it gets recognized as a delimiter.

The character `…`, encoded in UTF-8 is three `char`s:

```
E2 80 A6
```

Any one of those individual chars will be recognized by `strtok` as a valid delimiter for the string to be tokenized. These values will occur as part of other Chinese ideographs, resulting in `strtok` making mincemeat of the string that gets passed in for tokenization. `strtok` does not work with multibyte encodings.

If you need to implement this kind of tokenization using basic functions from the C library then the closest match would be `strstr`, which works in a completely different way. You'll need to reimplement this tokenization algorithm based on `strstr`.

Comment: what about solutions in c++? Is there any method can split char array by multiple chars?

Comment: Well, in C++ you'll have a `std::string` instead of arrays. And `std::string`'s overloaded `find()` is logically equivalent to `strstr()`. And if one still has a char array, then it's `std::search` together with iterator-based logic.

Comment: Luckily, UTF-8 is well-designed. `E2 80 A6`  can't occur as a substring spanning codepoint boundaries. If you find `E2 80 A6`, then `E2` is the start of a codepoint - it doesn't occur in the middle of codepoints. And every codepoint starting with `E2` is a 3-byte sequence.

Comment: @SamVarshavchi, can I use some method in c++ but don't use the data type, string or vector because I need to convert this file to dll file, someone told me it is better do not use heap memory data type

Comment: I already mentioned that option: "`std::search` together with iterator-based logic". Start with a plain `char` array, obtain an iterator to the beginning of the array and the end of its text, then start using `std::search` to plow through the entire sequence defined by iterators, from beginning to the end.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks for your reply again! but I only found some demo in tackling vector by `std::search`, could you please give some demo in how to split a char array by `std::search`?

Comment: Attempting to implement something in C++ by running a Google search, to find some code somewhere that does the same thing and then copy it, never works. C++ is just too complicated. Instead, one should ***learn*** and ***study*** how C++ works. It does not matter whether something is a vector or a char array. `std::search` is ***an algorithm***. The algorithm works ***exactly the same*** with any kind of a random access iterator, be it an iterator for a vector, a `std::string`, or a `char` array. Have you tried reading about `std::search` in your C++ textbook? Do you understand how it works?